# Jquery refresh image after source change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JavaScript function where I play a sound file (using phonegap). It normally works fine but I want to change the `img src` to a loading icon while the file is being downloaded. However, the src is changed
after the file is played.

I tried to add `+new Date().getTime()` to the end of src, but it didn't help. Any idea out there?

```
function playSound(){


var img = $(this).prev();

img.attr("src", "css/images/ajax-loader.gif?"+new Date().getTime());


var url = "http://some.com/fanky.mp3";   
mediaTTS = new Media(url, onSuccessTTS(url), onErrorTTS);
mediaTTS.play();

}
```

Comment: The delay is probably a preload issue. [A Google search on preload images through javascript](https://www.google.se/search?q=preload+images+javascript&aq=f&sugexp=chrome,mod=5&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Try that first, if it still exists we move on. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably due to the fact that the image is not re-drawn until the end of the current run loop. If `Media.play()` is blocking, you might not see the image change until it has finished playing.

To confirm my suspicion, please try this code:

```
function playSound(){
    var img = $(this).prev();
    img.attr("src", "css/images/ajax-loader.gif?"+new Date().getTime());
    setTimeout(function() {
        var url = "http://some.com/fanky.mp3";   
        mediaTTS = new Media(url, onSuccessTTS(url), onErrorTTS);
        mediaTTS.play();
    }, 100);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it was the problem. With your code, it updates the code and displays the loading animation, however, it blocks the animation for some time. But it is better than nothing.

Comment: Yea, it looks like your media element is blocking on the main thread. You should look in the docs and see if there is a way to have it preload asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove src attribute then add again with different src

```
function playSound(){
  var img = $(this).prev();
  img.removeAttr("src").attr("src","css/images/ajax-loader.gif?"+new Date().getTime());
  var url = "http://some.com/fanky.mp3";   
  mediaTTS = new Media(url, onSuccessTTS(url), onErrorTTS);
  mediaTTS.play();
}
```